# How to Uninstall FSearch software

Tags: apt, synaptic

I installed the search utility for fsearch byr running the following

```
sudo apt install git build-essential automake autoconf libtool pkg-config intltool autoconf-archive libpcre3-dev libglib2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libxml2-utils  

git clone https://github.com/cboxdoerfer/fsearch.git
cd fsearch

./autogen.sh
./configure
make && sudo make install
```

The software can by opened through the ubuntu launcher or by simply typing `fsearch` on the commandline

**How can i uninstall fsearch**
I've tried `sudo apt remove fsearch` by apt doesn't seem to locate the package fsearch

I also tried listing installed packages via `dpkg --list` , i still can't find fsearch

I've also tried looking up `fsearch` on the installed Tab of ubuntu software center, but i doesn't seem to be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use uninstallation script from make file:

```
cd fsearch
sudo make uninstall
```

Optionally you can remove its configuration files from `~/.config/fsearch`.

---

Also please note that deb-packages for such installation method are not created, so APT does not know about `fsearch` package.
If you want to get deb-package you have two options:

- Use [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware#Installing_the_Package)
- Use PPA - [`ppa:christian-boxdoerfer/fsearch-daily`](https://launchpad.net/~christian-boxdoerfer/+archive/ubuntu/fsearch-daily) (for this particular package)

Comment: Ohohoho! Thanks @N0rbert , that did the trick.